# База данных сущность связь

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Есть различные связи в базах данных:
Один ко многим,
Многие ко многим,
Один к одному..

Представим есть база данных Сериалы:
У сериалов есть сезоны
У сезонов есть эпизоды
Сколько нужно таблиц и какие связи между ними должны быть? Заранее благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вопросе уже есть половина ответа, но все-таки: 3 таблицы, две связи один-ко-многим (сериалы<-сезоны, сезоны<-эпизоды).
Многие-ко-многим тут не просматриваются, это скорее про отношения Актеры и Сериалы.

Comment: Я попробовал сделать так как вы написали но возникла проблема... Когда я добавляю к примеру 2 серию 3 сезона к любому сериалу то эта серия появляется во всех вторых сезонах всех сериалов... Не правильно соединил таблицы?)

Comment: Видимою Покажите как что соединили и как добавили (в исходном посте)

Answer (score 1):

**Я бы сделал так:**

Таблица Series с полями: ID, Name, Seasons

Таблица Episodes с полями: ID, ID_Series, Name, Season, Episode, Duration

Связь: `Series--1-----M--Episodes`

На сколько я понимаю, у сезонов нет каких-то отличительных признаков, чтобы делать для них отдельную таблицу. Это просто номер. Он, конечно, нужен для запросов будет, но для него хватит одного поля в таблице с эпизодами.

Можно вместо ID в таблице эпизодов сделать составной ключ, состоящий из полей: ID_Series, Season и Episode. Это будет уникально. Всё зависит от конечной цели.